# django user profile upload image

Tags: django

this is my model

my user model[image]

this is my modelform

i imported the user model[image]

the view [image]

and the template

[image]

i dont know what am doing wrong am new to django

Comment: Type the full code instead of posting image, how do we suppose to copy/paste your code to help you? and what is the question/issue?

Comment: Go through this [Link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) . It discusses file uploads in django model form.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the view and the template here:

In view:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    form = UpdateProfile()
    return render(request, 'explore/profile.html', {"form":form})
```

In template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Please check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) for more details.